# Why does following line gets ignored inside this function?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

can anyone explain why following line gets ignored:

```
 panelTest.SetActive(true);
```

full function code:

```
 public void getBaseData()
{
    Dictionary<string, object> data = null;
    if (firebase.getFirebaseAuth().CurrentUser == null)
        return;

    firebase.getDb().Collection("users").Document(firebase.getFirebaseAuth().CurrentUser.UserId).GetSnapshotAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsCompleted)
        {
            DocumentSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
            if (snapshot.Exists)
            {
                Debug.Log("Data found:");
                data = snapshot.ToDictionary();
                panelTest.SetActive(true);//gets ignored
            }
            else
            {
                //no entry for that user
                Debug.Log("snapshot doesnt exist");
            }
        }
       
    });
}
```

i dont get any error messages; also the line panelTest.SetActive(true); works fine outside the function.

Comment: because `GameObject.SetActive` belongs to the part (almost everything) of the Unity API that can only be used from the Unity **main thread** and `ContinueWith` is not giranteed to be executed on the main thread. See the duplicate link for the solution

Comment: @derHugo hey thank you so much for you reply; really helped me